# Browser showing nothing while calling servlet

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, jdbc, web-applications

I am trying this for a while but every time when i try to run on browser it shows nothing, not even an error.

**"index.html" file**

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Register form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="register">
    Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br/>
    Email ID:<input type="text" name="email" /><br/>
    Password:<input type="text" name="pass" /><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="register" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**"web.xml" file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app  version="3.0" 
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" >

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>Register</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>register</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/register</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**"Register.java" file**

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql:/ /localhost:3306/db","myuser","1234");

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
                  ("insert into Student values(?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);
        ps.setString(3, pass);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();

          if(i>0)
          {
            out.println("You are sucessfully registered");
          }

        }
        catch(Exception se)
        {
            se.printStackTrace();
        }

      }
  }
```

[This image is after i entered the details, and there is no data stored in my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOsnl.png)

[This is the error showing in cmd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkcNV.png)

I am using JDK 9 which have no "ext" file in the JRE so i included JDBC driver file through command line.

I have created database 'db' in mysql and table name 'student'.

I don't know where is the problem. Please help me!!

Comment: could you check server console ?

Answer (score -1):

Your form method is **post**:

```
<form method="post" action="register">
```

And in your servlet you only have a doGet.

Change your form method to **get**:

```
<form method="get" action="register">
```

**Servlet doGet:**

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
        try{

        //loading drivers for mysql
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

    //creating connection with the database 
          Connection  con=DriverManager.getConnection
                     ("jdbc:mysql:/ /localhost:3306/db","myuser","1234");

        PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
                  ("insert into Student (name,email,pass) values(?,?,?);");

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);
        ps.setString(3, pass);
        ps.executeUpdate();



        }catch(Exception se){
            se.printStackTrace();
        }
    //redirect user back to index
    RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("index.html");        
    rd.forward(request,response);  

      }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks @Jonathan Laliberte. But the problem is that the data which i'm entering through the register page is not storing in the database, even after  adding JDBC driver through command line, because in JDK 9, there is no "ext" folder to put JDBC file into it.

Comment: How would i know that until the values i'm entering is not stored in the database.

Comment: Your servlet is mapped onto the doGet request. Just type /register in your url and the servlet will run.

Comment: Look at your Servlet mapping name. You have to have a capital letter. All Servlets start with a capital letter. Change the servlet-name in web.xml. make sure it has a capital letter. Then restart your server. Also worth mentioning, is your Servlet inside a package?

Comment: yes, i tried with capital letter too but same result. And yes, Servlet is in WEB-INF/classes folder.

Comment: what do you mean the servlet is in WEB-INF classes folder? That's not normal. Can you link to a picture of your project setup? Showing all the important files in your project.

Comment: But i can't here. It is not allowed to upload Picture. In fact i tried to upload in question also but i couldn't. I can mail you if you give me your email address.

Comment: yeah you can. Use something like imgur and then send the link

Comment: i have attached two image links. One is register form page and second is after click submit button.

Comment: cool, but that doesn't really help. I need to see the project setup, so what it looks like in your project explorer, how the files are organized. What folder the servlet is in, that kind of thing.

Comment: but from your screenshot, the servlet is working from what i can see

Comment: @Hanut check out my edited answer, i cleaned up your Servlet. Try that code, let me know what happens. You should no longer get a blank screen

Comment: There was a problem with your sql statement also, please double check that your table is called "Student" with a capital 'S' and the fields are called, name,email,pass

Comment: i tried your servlet code but it is showing error while compiling the servlet in cmd.

Comment: wtf man, why are you looking at errors through cmd?? This explains very little. What happens when you run the site through your IDE? Presumably eclipse? What error do you get there?

Comment: No, I'm not using IDE. I'm only using cmd for learning purpose.

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: Did you copy my doGet method exactly as it says above?

Comment: yes i did, and then i also made change in HTML file from POST to GET.

Comment: i had the form element in my servlet code before editing it just now. Check make sure you don't have "<form method="get" action="register">" inside your servlet code.

Comment: Get on an IDE like eclipse, so you can troubleshoot the problems easier.

Answer (score -1):

You do not close Connection and PreparedStatement.
Best use try-with-resources for that. There was a space in the connection URL.
The other problem was already mentioned.

```
   try (Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection
                 ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db","myuser","1234");
            PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement
                 ("insert into Student (name,email,pass) values(?,?,?)")) {

        ps.setString(1, name);
        ps.setString(2, email);
        ps.setString(3, pass);
        ps.executeUpdate();
    } catch(Exception se) {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: i want to ask one thing, should i write my database name "db" after the port number 3306 ?

Comment: Yes, as several databases are imaginable, for instance for migration, playing.